# Extracting an array from a dataframe column that contains an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I am using thorns and cochlea to generate a spiketrain. The result is in the form of a pandas.DataFrame in the form, that the column 'spikes' contains the array of spiketimes that I need.

[DataFrame generated by thorns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7R6f.png)

When I try to extract it with

```
a = df.as_matrix(['spikes'])
```

the resulting matrix will always look like this:

```
a = [[array([1,2,3])][array([4,5,6])]]
```

to further use the data, i need the form:

```
a= [[1,2,3][4,5,6]]
```

how can I delete the array() part?

This is the code I use:

```
import cochlea

import thorns.waves as wv

#generating the spiketrain

sound = wv.ramped_tone(fs=100e3,freq=500,duration=0.3,dbspl=60)
spiketrain=cochlea.run_zilany2014(sound,fs=100e3,anf_num=(2,0,0),cf=500,seed=0,species='human')
print spiketrain

#trying to extrakt spiketime information
a = spiketrain.as_matrix(['spikes'])
print 'a='
print a
```

Comment: What is the actual shape of a?

Comment: If I use a.shape in my example a  is an array of the shape (2,1) the problem is the shape of the stored Data, which does not only contain the values but also the datatype in the form array([1,2,3])

Comment: Oh, if the shape is (2,1) then reshaping will not work. I started from a different initial array. I will try to look at it afterwards.

Comment: What is the output you get using `spiketrain['spikes'].values`? Is it the desired shape, if not, what is the shape?

Comment: With values it is still the shape array([1,2,3])

Comment: But then the individual entrys a[0] look normal at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9])]})

res = np.array(df['A'].values.tolist())

# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6],
#        [7, 8, 9]])

res2 = list(map(list, df['A']))

# [[1, 2, 3],
#  [4, 5, 6],
#  [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: It still looks the same, but I think I can use it now in the later model. Thanks

Comment: @Eli.K, sure - I added an alternative which may help you.

Comment: Yes, that is better, the second one generates the normal array form